# Error creating postgres container with Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm initializing my studies with docker. When I creating the postgreSQL container with Docker, appear this error:

[image]

I've already reinstall docker and tried change the database port, but must be don't have success

Comment: The error says that port 5432 is already in use. Did you try using another port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the 5432 port is already in use, in the **HOST**. This means that this port is occupied by another application. This could be for example a Postgres instance that you have on your machine or maybe another container using up this port.

The port option is `-p hostPort:ContainerPort`, so to have access to the Postgres port of the container which is 5432 in the host at port 5000 try:

```
-p 5000:5432
```